# Best practices to store a CLI program info

Tags: java, command-line-interface

My CLI Java program will display something like the following when launched:

```
MyProgramName [v1.0] (C) 2017 First Name Last Name
A one sentence to describe what the program is ...
```

What is the best practices to store each of the above info?

1) Static fields?
2) Methods?
3) Properties file?

Comment: private static final fields

Comment: Totally depends on your build environment. For example if the version information comes from the VCS it may make sense to take it from a properties file.

Comment: Depends - how much of that information is actually dynamic. Do you want to update the information yourself or have the build system do it?

Comment: One more thing to consider: you should decide if you want to support i18n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start with the most simple approach and look how it works, e.g. start with a simple `Info` class that assembles your descriptive texts.

If you want something more enhanced, take a look at [Typesafe's Config Library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

If internationalization is a topic you could also incorporate strategies from [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html)